# Single word for watching and/or tracking

Tags: terminology

On an online discussion forum, there is a count of "Unread" posts, but actually it's new activity in topics which are marked by the user as "watching" or "tracking" (which have specific consequences).

"Unread" is not really appropriate because there still may be unread posts which are not "watched" or "tracked". Is there a word (or two words?) which might communicate "new activity on topics in which you are active or have expressed interest"?

Thanks!

Comment: You have actually asked two questions here? One in your question title and and another about the new activity. Please clarify.

Comment: @vickyace thanks - yes I've clarified the text (hopefully). "New stuff you care about" is what I'm getting at, not sure how to say that succinctly.

Comment: Notifications. Favorites. Favorited. Your News.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **news** as in "news of interest."

> Newly received or noteworthy information. (Definition at [odo](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/news))

Another option is **concern** defined by Merriam Webster as

> (noun) something that relates to one
> (verb) to relate to

You can use **news, concerns, or concerning news**.

Comment: Thanks! New/News is sort of what I'm going for, only "new and you might care" is really what I am looking for. I like Noteworthy, that's close... "of interest" also might do it

Comment: To be honest "watching" is good, but that already means something very specific in this context.

Comment: @dhigger I don't understand what you mean? Isn't this out of context. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going with **following**, which seems appropriate (watching and/or tracking).

It's also commonly used in social media to imply "what I care about".

Comment: You can also use "tracking" as it will imply the watching part.